# How to make pushState/onpopstate and jQuery events (e.g. on click) work nicely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate

I am able to successfully use pushState and onpopstate to use the back/forward buttons on my AJAX enabled page.

One aspects of the AJAX feature is to automatically refresh a dropdown list when a link in clicked. This is my code this feature.

```
<a class="type" href="#Chr(35)#" data-type="B">B</a>
| <a class="type" href="#Chr(35)#" data-type="H">H</a>

window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    if (event.state) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = event.state.html;
    }
});

$(".type").on("click", function (event) {
    console.log("im here");

    event.preventDefault();

    getCourses({ type:$(this).data("type") });

    try {
        window.history.pushState({ "html": document.getElementById("content").innerHTML }, "", globalvars.baseurl+"/my/main?type="+$(this).data("type"));
    } catch(exception) {
    }
});
```

The problem happens when I press the back button and it renders a saved copy of the content section. When I try to click the links above, it wouldn't trigger (i.e. "im here" won't display now in my console where it used to work before I pressed the back button)

**It seems the solution is to copy the link's on-click function inside my event listener particularly after "if (event.state)...".**

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    if (event.state) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = event.state.html;

        $(".type").on("click", function (event) { console.log("im here") });
    }
});

$(".type").on("click", function (event) {
    console.log("im here");

    event.preventDefault();

    getCourses({ type:$(this).data("type") });

    try {
        window.history.pushState({ "html": document.getElementById("content").innerHTML }, "", globalvars.baseurl+"/my/main?type="+$(this).data("type"));
    } catch(exception) {
    }
});
```

That means I need to write the same code in 2 places. The only alternative I can think of is to remove the contents of the on-click function and put it inside a custom function.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(event) {
    if (event.state) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = event.state.html;

        $(".type").on("click", function (event) { test($(this).data("type")); });
    }
});

$(".type").on("click", function (event) { test($(this).data("type")); });

function test(type) {
    console.log("im here");

    event.preventDefault();

    getCourses({ type:type });

    try {
        window.history.pushState({ "html": document.getElementById("content").innerHTML }, "", globalvars.baseurl+"/my/main?type="+type);
    } catch(exception) {
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Btw, you're not "writing the same code twice", you're writing your pushState code once, in the click handler, and it is being invoked by two similar methods, a genuine user click or a triggered click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of ways... one is storing the inside function in a variable:

```
var typeClickHandler = function (event) {
  test($(this).data("type"));
};
```

and then using that handler when you need it, in both places:

```
$(".type").on("click", typeClickHandler);
```

Other way is to use event delegation... this means that the listener is on document or some parent of this element that you want to listen to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.type', function (event) {
  // note that we use event.target instead of this here
  test($(event.target).data("type"));
});
```

and of course, you can combine those two solutions:

```
var typeClickHandler = function (event) {
  test($(event.target).data("type"));
};
$(document).on('click', '.type', typeClickHandler);
```

Comment: Btw if event delegation is new to you, I suggest that you read up on "javascript event bubbling" to understand how that works.